# If $b_n$ is a bounded sequence then there exists $N_0$ for every $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. $b_n\in(\lim\inf{b_n}-\varepsilon, \lim\sup{b_n}+\varepsilon)$

Tags: real-analysis

We proved the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem in class, and were given the following conclusion without proof:

For any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$\forall{n>N_0}:\ \ b_n\in\left({\underset{n\to\infty}\lim\inf{b_n}}-\varepsilon, \underset{n\to\infty}\lim\sup{b_n}+\varepsilon\right)$$

I tried proving this conclusion on my own, but I got somewhat lost with writing down everything formally.

I can see that if for the sake of contradiction there is a finite number of elements in this neighborhood for some $\varepsilon_0>0$, then you'd be able to build a subsequence of $b_n$ that converges to an invalid limit that contradicts given limsup/liminf, but I am unable to make this notion precise.

How would you go about proving this claim by imagining a subsequence that would lead to a contradiction? (Other ways that derive from Bolzano-Weierstrass are more than welcome).

Comment: Oops, they gave us two phrasings of this claim. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

1. By contradiction, suppose that there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\forall N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists n > N_0$ with $b_n \notin (\liminf_{k \rightarrow +\infty} b_k-\varepsilon, \limsup_{k \rightarrow +\infty} b_k+\varepsilon)$
2. Show that this implies that an infinity of the $b_n$'s lie outside the interval $(\liminf_{k \rightarrow +\infty} b_k-\varepsilon, \limsup_{k \rightarrow +\infty} b_k+\varepsilon)$.
3. Wlog, suppose that an infinity of the $b_n$'s is $\geq  \limsup_{k \rightarrow +\infty} b_k+\varepsilon$.
4. Show that there exists an subsequence $(b_{\varphi(n)})$ such that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $b_{\varphi(n)} \geq \limsup_{k \rightarrow +\infty} b_k+\varepsilon$
5. Show that $\limsup_{k \rightarrow +\infty} b_k \geq \limsup_{k \rightarrow +\infty} b_{\varphi(k)} \geq \limsup_{k \rightarrow +\infty} b_k+\varepsilon$, and get a contradiction.